# Problem with Flask wtforms validation errors

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

Flask wtforms doesn't show validation errors (eg. when password dont match).
**forms.py**

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, BooleanField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Length, Email, ValidationError, EqualTo, Regexp

class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=5, message='Name length must be between %(min)d')]), Regexp("^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_.]*$", 0, "Username must have")
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=8, message='Password should be at least %(min)d characters long')])
    confirm_password = PasswordField('Confirm Password', validators=[DataRequired(message='*Required'), EqualTo('password', message='Both password fields must be equal!')])
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    register = SubmitField('Register')
```

respective snippet from **registration.html**

```
<div class = "input-group mb-3">
{{form.confirm_password.label(class="form control table")}}
{{form.confirm_password(class="form-control form-control-lg", id="floatingPassword", placeholder="Confirm Password")}}
   </div>
      {% for error in form.password.errors %}
       <div class="alert alert-danger input-group" role="alert">
        <span style="color: red;">{{ error }}</span>
       </div>
       {% endfor %}
```

and snippet from route function **views.py**

```
@custodian_view.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    form = RegistrationForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.validate_on_submit:
            user = Account(email=form.email.data, username=form.username.data, password=form.password.data)
            db.session.add(user)
            db.session.commit()
```

Please, advice how can I fix this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the passwords don't match, the error message will be sent via form.**confirm_password**.errors.
So you have to change this line:

```
{% for error in form.password.errors %}
```

into this:

```
{% for error in form.confirm_password.errors %}
```